# Deletion query fetching values of a string

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net, delete-row

I have to delete a row from database. The condition is when a string is equal to the field url:

```
public void Delete_Piece(string ur)
{
    this.Connect();
    using (connexion)
    {
        using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("Delete  Piece where Url like @ur", connexion))
        {    
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ur", ur);
            try
                {
                    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                 }
            catch { }       
        }
    }
}
```

The type of the field `Url` is Text and the type of the parametrs `Ur` is string. I'am sure that there is a value like the string but always any row is deleted!!

1. Where is the error?
2. How can I fix it?

Comment: Don't ignore the exception and post what it says

Comment: It would be easier if you tell us what is the error.

Comment: Isn't there a `"FROM"` missing? `"DELETE FROM [Tablename] WHERE [Fieldname] LIKE @FieldValue"`.

Comment: there is no exception but the deletion not works despite the existence of a similar value in the table

Comment: Add a message in the catch block `catch(Exception ex) {MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented, you are missing the `FROM` clause on your delete statement. [Check DELETE sintax on BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Basic sintax is:

```
DELETE FROM [Tablename] WHERE [Fieldname] LIKE @FieldValue
```

So it should be:

```
DELETE FROM Piece WHERE Url = @ur
```

Comment: the exception is the following `The data types text and nvarchar are incompatible in the equal to operator.`

Comment: The exception speaks for itself, you are comparing a `nvarchar` and a `text`. You should use [CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms187928.aspx) Be aware that Microsoft is depreciating `ntext` type, check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx).

Comment: Then don't use equal. Use `LIKE`.

Comment: the same thing with `using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("Delete From Piece where
                           CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), Url) =@ur", connexion))`

Comment: Check @ur type, there is some type mismatch between the parameters

Answer (score 1):

Your `SqlCommand` is not properly formatted. Your query should like this:

```
DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE some_column=some_value
```

In your case :

```
using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("Delete From Piece where
                           CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), Url) =@ur", connexion))
  {
      //Your code
  }
```

Comment: the exception is the following `The data types text and nvarchar are incompatible in the equal to operator.`

Comment: Use `LIKE` (as in OP) and you shouldn't need to convert.

Comment: What is the DataType for `Url`